# MySQL query to find the count of each item in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, aggregation

I have a table with the following fields :
user_id, occured_at, event_type, event_name, location, device, user_type

[image: table]

**question to solve :**
Weekly Engagement: To measure the activeness of a user. Measuring if the user finds quality in a product/service weekly.
Your task: Calculate the weekly engagement per device?

I have found a solution for this, which is to find the distinct devices and then use a separate query to find the weekly engagement per device by manually specifying the device names in IN statement.

**Query 1 :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT device AS devices
FROM events1;
```

**Output :**

dell inspiron notebook iphone 5 iphone 4s windows surface macbook air iphone 5s macbook pro kindle fire ipad mini nexus 7 nexus 5 samsung galaxy s4 lenovo thinkpad samsumg galaxy tablet acer aspire notebook asus chromebook htc one nokia lumia 635 samsung galaxy note acer aspire desktop mac mini hp pavilion desktop dell inspiron desktop ipad air amazon fire phone nexus 10

**Query2 :**

```
SELECT week(occurred_at) AS weeknum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS weekly_users,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN device IN ('macbook pro', 'acer aspire notebook','acer aspire desktop','lenovo thinkpad', 'mac mini', 'dell inspiron desktop','dell inspiron notebook','windows surface','macbook air','asus chromebook','hp pavilion desktop') THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS computer,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN device IN ('iphone 5s','nokia lumia 635','amazon fire phone','iphone 4s','htc one','iphone 5','samsung galaxy s4') THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS phone,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN device IN ('kindle fire','samsung galaxy note','ipad mini','nexus 7','nexus 10','samsumg galaxy tablet','nexus 5','ipad air') THEN user_id ELSE NULL END) AS tablet
FROM events1 
WHERE event_type = 'engagement'
AND event_name = 'login'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ;
```

**final output**

[image: final output]

**My doubt:**
Is there a way to find this result using a single query which finds weekly users for each device like ('macbook pro', 'acer aspire notebook','acer aspire desktop','lenovo thinkpad' etc ) instead of first finding the device names and manually entering them as in two separate queries.
Here we have 26 device names, so we are able to manually enter it. What if there are lot of devices and it becomes impossible for us to enter it manually. What will we do in those situations. Can anyone please suggest a solution.

Comment: Try to improve your post by going through these [tips for asking a good sql question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Comment: You should not upload images of code/data/errors https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: You don't appear to know what type a device is (phone,computer,tablet...) so you will have to categorise them in your query. Perhaps a devices table would help.

Comment: [Can you share the sql with sample data and query in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: You must add device type when storing data, guessing by name is not possible.

Comment: The question says - `Your task: Calculate the weekly engagement per device?`  Where does your device type interpretation come from? Surely you should be grouping `per device`, as suggested in the question?